# Node.js adding multiple properties to an object

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm wondering if there's a better way of doing this:

```
module.exports.foo = "bar";
module.exports.bar = "baz";
module.exports.foobar = "foobaz";
```

Now, I've heard about 'with' (and its dangers) but it doesn't work here because it can't add new properties to an object, it can only change existing properties.  In fact if you try to add new properties you end up clobbering the enclosing scope which isn't very nice.

Something like this would be nice:

```
module.exports += {
  foo: "bar",
  bar: "baz",
  foobar: "foobaz"
}
```

But that converts both sides to strings before concatenating them which is not what I want.

Does such syntactic sugar exist in Node.JS-flavoured JavaScript?  Maybe a function on 'module' to add lots of properties at once?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could write a simple function to loop over them and add them to module.exports or you can try [node.extend](https://github.com/dreamerslab/node.extend) which tries to mimic jquery's `$.extend()`

Comment: I think the loop is the lesser of those two evils.

Answer (score 1):

Use [Object.assign()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign)

```
Object.assign(module.exports, {
              foo: "bar",
              bar: "baz",
              foobar: "foobaz"
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider using [_.extend](http://underscorejs.org/#extend)

So in your example:

```
            module.exports += {
              foo: "bar",
              bar: "baz",
              foobar: "foobaz"
            }
```

Would be:

```
            var _ = require('underscore');

            _.extend(module.exports,
                {
                  foo: "bar",
                  bar: "baz",
                  foobar: "foobaz"
                }
            );
```

Or, if you do not want any dependencies, using raw javascript:

```
            function myExtend(dest, obj) {
                for (key in obj) {
                    var val = obj[key];
                    dest[key] = val;
                }
            }
            myExtend(module.exports,
                {
                  foo: "bar",
                  bar: "baz",
                  foobar: "foobaz"
                }
            );
```

If you are using the latter method, make sure to check for edge cases, which I haven't here!